# i need help implementing my event manager and engine system (SDL && C++)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, sdl

i need help with my attempt at writing a reusable game engine.  it's not the best engine, but i definitely think it will be reusable once i am done.  i am not asking for code or to be spoonfed, but i am asking for some advice :-).

my current layout:

i have an engine class, a game class, and an event manager class.  the engine class extends the event manager class, and the game class extends the engine class.  here is my current code for these 3 classes (ignore the Graphics class--it is just a reusable class i use to avoid rewriting fullscreen, initialize, and resize screen functions).

ENGINE.HPP

```
#ifndef _ENGINE_HPP
#define _ENGINE_HPP

#pragma once

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include "event_manager.hpp"

enum
  {
    ENGINE_SUCCESS = 0,
    ENGINE_INITIALIZATION_ERROR
  };

class Engine : public EventManager
{
public:
  Engine();
  virtual ~Engine();
  int exec();
  void handle_event(SDL_Event *);
  void update_engine();
  virtual bool init();
  virtual void render();
  virtual void update();
  virtual void clean();
  bool running_;
};
```

ENGINE.CPP

```
#include "./engine.hpp"

Engine::Engine()
{
  running_ = false;
}

Engine::~Engine()
{
}

int Engine::exec()
{
  if (!init())
    {
      clean();
      return ENGINE_INITIALIZATION_ERROR;
    }

  SDL_Event event;
  while (running_)
    {
      while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    handle_event(&event);

      update();
      render();
    }

  clean();
  return ENGINE_SUCCESS;
}

void update_engine()
{
}

void handle_event(SDL_Event *event)
{
  EventManager::handle_event(event);
}

bool init() {return true;}
void render() {}
void update() {}
void clean() {}
```

EVENT_MANAGER.HPP

```
#ifndef _EVENT_MANAGER_HPP
#define _EVENT_MANAGER_HPP

#pragma once

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

class EventManager
{
public:
  EventManager();
  virtual ~EventManager();
  virtual void handle_event(SDL_Event *);
  // events here
  virtual void event_exit();
};

#endif
```

EVENT_MANAGER.CPP

```
#include "./event_manager.hpp"

EventManager::EventManager() 
{
}

EventManager::~EventManager()
{
}

void EventManager::handle_event(SDL_Event *event)
{
  switch (event->type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
      event_exit();
      break;
    }
}

void on_exit() {}
```

GAME.HPP

```
#ifndef _GAME_HPP
#define _GAME_HPP

#include "./engine.hpp"
#include "./entity.hpp"
#include "./graphics.hpp"

class Game : public Engine
{
public:
  Game();
  bool init();
  void render();
  void update();
  void clean();
private:
  Graphics g;
};

#endif
```

GAME.CPP

```
#include "./game.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Engine engine;
  return engine.exec();
}

Game::Game() {}

bool Game::init()
{
  if (!g.init(800, 600, 32, g.screen_flags()))
    {
      return false;
    }

  SDL_WM_SetCaption("Title", NULL);
  return true;
}

void Game::update()
{
  Engine::update_engine();
}

void Game::clean()
{
  SDL_FreeSurface(g.screen_);
  SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::render()
{
  SDL_Flip(g.screen_);
}
```

i am getting this error:

```
engine.cpp: In function ‘void handle_event(SDL_Event*)’:
engine.cpp:40: error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void
EventManager::handle_event(SDL_Event*)’ without object
```

why is this happening?  shouldn't i be able to do EventManager:: if the I did

```
class Engine : public EventManager
```

???

that is the only error i get, i am sure it is something simple.  now i need a little bit of advice.

instead of handling events like

```
void Engine::event_exit()
```

in the engine, i'd rather do it in the game class.

```
class Game : public Engine


void Game::event_exit()
```

if that doesn't make sense, notice how i made Engine extend EventManager, and my Game class extends Engine

```
class Engine : public EventManager

class Game : public Engine
```

would it work if i called the snippet above these ^ two snippets?  i can't test it because i get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Happens to the best of us, but I think it's just a matter of forgetting to specify namespaces. When you implement the functions in `engine.cpp`, you forgot to prepend `Engine::`, so the code should be:

```
void Engine::update_engine()
{
}

void Engine::handle_event(SDL_Event *event)
{
    EventManager::handle_event(event);
}
```

It's a classic case of C++ error messages not really telling you the *root* of the error.

A short explanation, just in case:

The compiler tried to compile the **function** `void handle_event(SDL_Event *event)`, and saw a call to a **method** `EventManager::handle_event(event);`. Since the compiler thought the function was not part of the Engine class, it would expect you to call the method of a *particular* instance of the `EventManager` class, i.e.

```
someEventManager->handle_event(event);
```

As soon as you specify that the implementation you wrote is that of a method, belonging to the class `Engine`, the compiler essentially deduces:

```
void Engine::handle_event(SDL_Event *event)
{
    this->EventManager::handle_event(event);
}
```

And therefore is happy.

Comment: Like I said, happens to the best of us :) . You almost have to develop an internal mapping of **compiler error message** -> **probable cause** in your head to deal with these kinds of things. Otherwise these kinds of errors in the code are usually missed when looking through it visually.